# Git SSH keeps asking for password when cloning

Tags: git, ssh

I read a lot of similar topics here, but couldn't find a solution.

My SSH keypair `mp` and `mp.pub` is stored in `~/.ssh/`. I've deployed the public key on the git-rep-server as I always do.

I added the host to `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host git.myhost.de
      HostName git.myhost.de
      User git
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mp
```

I tried out the configuration with `ssh -T git@git.myhost.de` and I got access using my passphrase and it listed all the repositories I'm allowed to read and write.

However, trying to clone a repository with `sudo git clone git@git.myhost.de:myrep.git` ends up with

```
Cloning into 'dict'...
git@git.myhost.de's password:
```

Since I don't even know the password I would like to use my ssh passphrase. What's wrong here? I always did it this way and it used to work, but with my new Ubuntu installation it doesn't work suddenly.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo` means `~` won't be interpreted correctly (in `~/.ssh/mp` of the `~/.ssh/config`).

You can try and put the full absolute path of your private key in the config file, which should be read by `root` (meaning it would look for the `.ssh/config` in root homedir).

Comment: Oohh.. of course. Thank you! I did it without sudo and it worked. I will accept the answer as soon as I'm allowed to.